# Changing the shortcut used to open the Magnifier in Windows 10

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts

**Fn+Tab** does two things:

1. Open the Magnifier at 200%.
2. Move forward a tab in Microsoft Visual Studio.

It is almost never desirable to do both of these actions simultanenously. Fixing formatting while programming is sometimes necessary, yet each attempt at doing so means opening the Magnifier.

**Fn + Tab** is a very convenient shortcut for moving forward a tab, and this is done far more often than opening a magnifier. Thus, it makes more sense to change the shortcut that opens the Magnifier, rather than the shortcut responsible for changing formatting.

Problem is that I don't know how to change this shortcut. I'd appreciate help.

Comment: This shouldn't work with FN but rather Alt and Windows. By default there shouldn't be a common key combination for both. Did you already customize this? This might be caused by custom software from your Notebook vendor, do you have that installed?

Comment: No, I haven't customized it. I'm using Thinkpad E14, if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

The shortcut <kbd>Win</kbd><kbd>+</kbd> will start the Magnifier at
100%, and if used again will further zoom-in.
(This is used with the <kbd>+</kbd> key of the Numpad.)

For more shortcuts see
[Magnifier keyboard shortcuts and touch gestures](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/magnifier-keyboard-shortcuts-and-touch-gestures-6d7c3095-75ec-258f-6f5b-3b0bc19a18e7).